# How to invert Sensor output signal?

Tags: port

I have a 24V sensor that outputs high when it detects something. I want it to output LOW when it detects something so the lamp (24V 18mA) stays off.

[image]

My solution for this problem was using a not port with transistor and resistors.

[image]

Any help that requires less hardware?

Comment: Well, for one thing, R3 is not necessary. And R1 should have a higher value -- more like 47K.

Comment: ok. How did u calculate that?

Comment: I didn't; I just drew on my vast experience :-) But seriously, the base current only needs to be about one tenth of the collector current.

Comment: the 10k on R2 is ok then?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the rest of your circuit. 10K would be fine for driving a 5V logic input. But you mentioned a 24V lamp, which would be completely different.

Comment: it's 24v input. check the link on top. the round thing is the sensor. Imagine the circuit above before the lamp...

Comment: Could be done with 1 PNP transistor and 1 resistor.

Comment: @brhans care to make a simple diagram on paint?

Comment: @dadaad As Dave pointed out, R3 is not necessary. Since we don't have any info about where will the output of this NOT gate connected to, we cannot say that 10k for R2 is acceptable. Just remember that the transistor should be saturated when A is applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you just connect the lamp between output and +24 volts. When the output is high, the lamp will be off. When the output is low, the lamp will be on. I'm presuming that the output can sink lamp current as well as it can source lamp current (as implied in your first picture).

Comment: what should work. There is not risk of burning the sensor if the current goes inside the signal? maybe it's better so use a diode?

Comment: i tried this and the led voltage is only 0.2V. it doesnt work.

Comment: Please provide a link to the sensor.

Answer (score 1):

If the lamp must be connected to ground, then the PNP circuit would look like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHoOie.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This still requires the sensor to be able to sink current, but not the full current of the lamp.

---

EDIT: Since you finally made it clear in your [followup question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/301912/11683) (which really should have been an edit to this question) that your sensor has a PNP (open-collector) output that can't sink current, then you need a slightly modified circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fP7zVJ.png)</sup>